# Problem involving Hölder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have to solve the following exercise.

> Given a bounded sequence $(f_n)_n \subset L^{3}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n \ge 0$ and such that $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ in the space $L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$, show that 
>   $$
> f_n \xrightarrow[L^2(\mathbb{R})]{} f.
> $$

**My attempt:** 
I used the Hölder inequality and I got:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} | f_n - f|^2 dx \le \Big( \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n - f|^3 dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Big( \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n - f|^{\frac{3}{2}} dx \Big)^{\frac{2}{3}}
$$

but I can't show that the sequence 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n - f|^3 dx 
$$
is bounded.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$|f_n-f|^3 \leq 2^3 (|f_n|^3+|f|^3)$$

we have

$$\int |f_n-f|^3 \, dx \leq 8 \int |f_n|^3 \, dx + 8 \int |f|^3 \, dx \leq 8 \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \int |f_k|^3 \, dx + 8 \int |f|^3 \, dx.$$

The first expression on the right-hand side is finite since $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $L^3(\mathbb{R})$. It remains to check that $f \in L^3(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f_n \to f$ in $L^{3/2}$, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k}$ which converges almost everywhere to $f$. Applying Fatou's lemma, we find

$$\begin{align*} \int |f|^3 \, dx = \int \liminf_{k \to \infty} |f_{n_k}|^3 \, dx  &\leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int |f_{n_k}|^{3} \, dx \\  &\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int |f_n|^3 \, dx < \infty. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I just don't understand the need of the constant $2^3$ but everything is very clear! Thanks!

Comment: @Onil90 Well, the inequality $$|f_n-f|^3 \leq |f_n|^3 + |f|^3$$ does, in general, not hold true (consider e.g. $f_n = 1$, $f = -1$)... that's why we need an additional constant on the right-hand side. The inequality which I use can be proved as follows: $$|f_n-f|^3 \leq (2 \max(|f_n|,|f|))^3 = 2^3 \max(|f_n|^3,|f|^3) \leq 2^3 (|f_n|^3+|f|^3).$$

Comment: oh yeah! Sorry.. I'm just a bit tired..

Comment: @Onil90 You are welcome. Good night :)